# Why is the "geometry" package passed an unwanted argument?

Tags: documentclass-writing, class-options

I am working on a class and cannot figure out why geometry is passed my argument "twocolumn", even though I did not use \RequirePackageWithOptions but only \RequirePackage. Can someone explain to me how I can circumvent this strange behaviour ?

Class file

```
\ProvidesClass{toto}
\DeclareOption{twocolumn}{}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass[a4paper]{article}
\RequirePackage{geometry}
\endinput
```

Main .tex file

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{toto}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Global options are passed to every loaded package and `geometry` has its own `twocolumn` option.

If you want to nullify it, do

```
\ProvidesClass{toto}
\DeclareOption{twocolumn}{}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass[a4paper]{article}
\RequirePackage[twocolumn=false]{geometry}
\endinput
```

Comment: If I remove the \RequirePackage{geometry}, then why is the "twocolumn" option not passed through the \LoadClass[a4paper]{article} ? Are global options passed only to packages and not to classes ?

Comment: @Florian Exactly.